# Matrix with boolean values from a list of paired observations

Tags: excel, matrix, boolean

In the below spreadsheet, the cell values represent an ID for a person. The person in column A likes the person in column B, but it may not be mutual. So, in the first row with data, person 1 likes 2. In the second row with data person 1 likes 3.

```
A B    
1 2    
1 3    
2 1    
2 4    
3 4    
4 1
```

I'm looking for a way to have a 4 x 4 matrix with an entry of 1 in (i,j) to indicate person i likes person j and an entry of 0 to indicate they don't. The example above should like this after performing the task:

```
  1 2 3 4
1 0 1 1 0    
2 1 0 0 1    
3 0 0 0 1    
4 1 0 0 0
```

So, reading the first row of the matrix we would interpret it like this: person 1 does not like person 1 (cell value = 0), person 1 likes person 2 (cell value = 1), person 1 likes person 3 (cell value =1), person 1 does not like person 4 (cell value = 0)

Note that order of pairing matter so `[4   2]` does not equal `[2    4]`.

How could this be done?

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? It's unclear to me how you map your column values to the binary representation and I'm confused about the boolean context.

Comment: Sorry, so in the above there are 4 people.  The person in column A likes the person in column B but it may not be mutual.  I'm looking for a way to have a 4x4 matrix with an entry of 1 in (i,j) to indicate person i likes person j and an entry of 0 to indicate they don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your existing data is in `A1:B6`, then in `A10` enter:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$6, ROW()-9,$B$1:$B$6, COLUMN())
```

This will return a 1 or a 0 depending on whether person `1` likes person `1`. They don't so you get a 0. It uses `Row()-9` to return `1` and `COLUMN()` to return `1` to find the match.

Copy this formula over 4 columns and down 4 rows and that `ROW()-9` and `COLUMN()` formula will return the appropriate values for the check into the `COUNTIFS()` formula which will look for the matching pair.

[image]

Personally, if this was something I had to do and my matrix was of indeterminate size, I would probably stick these formulas on a second tab, starting at `A1` and use `ROW()` where I don't have to adjust it by `9`. But for a one off on the same tab, to help check the results, the above is fine.

Comment: thank you so much.  By second tab do you mean Sheet 2?

Comment: Yes. Just another tab in the workbook. Then you can copy and paste the formula across many rows and columns to match the max(A:A) or max(B:B) from the tab containing your list of relationships.